# Need help in explaining Instr Function code below

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript

Just want to ask why is the output for this line of code '18', I'm not very particular with Instr Function in Lotusscript.

```
    Dim expview as String
    expview = Instr("OpenAgent&query=&expview=","expview=")
    Print expview
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is index of character in string `OpenAgent&query=&expview=` from which string `expview=` starts.